# what is the formula to calculate minNominated dynamic value in Polkadot staking?

Tags: polkadot, polkadot-js, staking, minnominated

As illustrated in Polkadot.js.org staking page which is added below, users who staked more than "min nominated" will receive rewards. minNominated is a dynamic value. I found the code in Polkadot js app [link](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/blob/cb60c73daa1febb6ccc78fdf82759ded359e4f0d/packages/page-staking/src/useSortedTargets.ts#L105) but does not help a lot. could someone please let me know find the formula to calculate the minNominated?

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Min active nominated value is not based on a formula. The [bags-list](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_bags_list/) implementation basically sorts the nominators who submitted their nomination intent and takes a snapshot of the top 22,500 nominators and submits it for NPoS election. The min nominated value you see in the screenshot is the minimum stake among the active nominators for that era.

https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-nominator#required-minimum-stake

Comment: Thanks, another questions came up:  this bag is sorted based on VoteWeight, which should be the staked amount, right? is the sorted bag includes all nominators which nominates current era's active validators? hence, a nominator with a staked value more than minNominated, who nominated some non-waiting validators should receive rewards in that era?